# Moving Mail between Exchange Mail Queues

Tags: email, exchange-2007

We have multiple Microsoft Exchange 2007 nodes and 2 Exchange hubs.  One of our users unfortunately had their account compromised, which then sent out several thousand emails before we were able to stop them.  During this time, however, several primary mail providers blocked one of our Exchange hubs as a spam source.  We now have nearly 500 messages built up on the one hub server waiting to go out to a provider who is currently blocking that hub.

I know it is possible to change the location of the mailqueue and I could copy the queue database over from one hub to another and than change the location the HUB is looking at to a different file - let the mail spool out and then change the location back, but I would like a cleaner solution.

Therefore, the question: is there a way to quickly and easily move messages from one Exchange hub server to another Exchange hub server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a permanent way is to just change the public IP address of the hub to a IP that hasn't been blacklisted.

Second, rather then moving messages from hub to hub manually, you need to change your routing in the Exchange org so that all External mail has to be routed through the "good" hub.  In Exchange console under Org Hub Transport, look for the rule that sends all mail to Internet, and change the "source server" list to be the good hub only.  Then that should eventually change routing on bad hub that it can't send out directly and has to relay through good hub.  I would restart exchange services on bad hub after this change to quicken the result.

Comment: Just because we have so many 10s of thousands of users, and customers' replying to phishing emails etc. we frequently deal with spammers, so changing our public IP isn't an option.

However, what we decided to do was go into the Exchange transport configuration and create a new smart host route for mail when we need to.  This allows us to forward all mail in a queue on HUB A to Hub B and vise versa when necessary. This change also takes effect without needing to restart services, which is nice is a large scale environment.

Comment: Great, if my answer helped answer the question please mark it so, thanks.